# Python least means squares adaptive filter implementation

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a least means squares adaptive filter in python similar to that of [least_squares](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.least_squares.html) in scipy. I'm trying to follow the [wikipedia-defined algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_mean_squares_filter#Simplifications) for the least means squares adaptive filter, but I can't seem to update my independent variables properly.

What am I missing in my implementation?

#### Code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import least_squares

def desiredFunc(x):
    """desired response"""
    aa0 = 1.39
    bb0 = 4.43
    return aa0*np.power(x,3) + bb0

def myFunc(x, a0, b0):
    return a0*np.power(x,3) + b0

def myMinFunc(a0, b0, x):
    """minimization function"""
    return desiredFunc(x) - myFunc(x, a0, b0)

def mse(errors):
    """mean square error"""
    return sum(np.square(errors))/len(errors)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a0_bounds = [-3, 3] # [lower bound, upper bound]
    b0_bounds = [-5, 5] # [lower bound, upper bound]
    a0_scale = 10
    b0_scale = 10

    x0 = [0, 0] # initial guess of independent variables
    # bounds for scipy implementation
    #bounds = ([a0_bounds[0], b0_bounds[0]], [a0_bounds[1], b0_bounds[1]])
    f = np.arange(-10, 11)

    ########################
    #### scipy least_squares
    ########################
    #ans = least_squares(lambda param: myMinFunc(param[0], param[1], f), x0, bounds=bounds, x_scale=[a0_scale, b0_scale], verbose = 2)
    #print(ans.x)

    ########################
    #### implementation
    ########################
    # bounds for own implementation
    bounds = [a0_bounds, b0_bounds]

    # initial error array
    errors = myMinFunc(x0[0], x0[1], f)
    print(f'MSE: {mse(errors):.2f}\t(Sum of err)/N: {sum(errors)/len(errors):.2f}\tind. variables: [{x0[0]:.2f},{x0[1]:.2f}]')

    while mse(errors) > 10:
        # adjust independent variables
        for i, param in enumerate(x0):

            x0[i] =  x0[i] + 1/len(errors)/a0_scale*sum(errors) # unbiased estimator from wikipedia

            # check if bounds are violated:
            if x0[i] > bounds[i][1]:
                x0[i] = bounds[i][1]
            if x0[i] < bounds[i][0]:
                x0[i] = bounds[i][0]

        # measure system
        errors = myMinFunc(x0[0], x0[1], f)
        print(f'MSE: {mse(errors):.2f}\t(Sum of err)/N: {sum(errors)/len(errors):.2f}\tind. variables: [{x0[0]:.2f},{x0[1]:.2f}]')
        input('Press Enter to continue...')
```

#### Output:

```
$ python3 least-squares-implementation.py 
MSE: 364064.99  (Sum of err)/N: 4.43    ind. variables: [0.00,0.00]
MSE: 168992.22  (Sum of err)/N: 3.99    ind. variables: [0.44,0.44]
Press Enter to continue...
MSE: 56657.98   (Sum of err)/N: 3.59    ind. variables: [0.84,0.84]
Press Enter to continue...
MSE: 6774.48    (Sum of err)/N: 3.23    ind. variables: [1.20,1.20]
Press Enter to continue...
MSE: 3365.35    (Sum of err)/N: 2.91    ind. variables: [1.52,1.52]
Press Enter to continue...
MSE: 33900.81   (Sum of err)/N: 2.62    ind. variables: [1.81,1.81]
Press Enter to continue...
```

Comment: Use a debugger and step through your code. If you don't know how to use a debugger, add a bunch of `print()` to print out the values of the variables at each iteration

Answer (score 0):

After some playing around, I have a somewhat working implementation. This implementation doesn't work if the initial independent variables in x0 are initialized to zero.

#### Code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import least_squares

def desiredFunc(x):
    """desired response"""
    aa0 = 1.39
    bb0 = 4.43
    return aa0*np.power(x,3) + bb0

def myFunc(x, a0, b0):
    return a0*np.power(x,3) + b0

def myMinimizingFunc(a0, b0, x):
    """minimization function"""
    # desired function - estimated function
    return desiredFunc(x) - myFunc(x, a0, b0)

def mse(errors):
    """mean square error"""
    return sum(np.square(errors))/len(errors)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a0_bounds = [-5, 5] # [lower bound, upper bound]
    b0_bounds = [-5, 5] # [lower bound, upper bound]
    a0_scale = 10
    b0_scale = 10

    x0 = [0.1, 0.3] # initial guess of independent variables
    # bounds for scipy implementation
    #bounds = ([a0_bounds[0], b0_bounds[0]], [a0_bounds[1], b0_bounds[1]])
    f = np.arange(-10, 11)

    ########################
    #### scipy least_squares
    ########################
    #ans = least_squares(lambda param: myMinimizingFunc(param[0], param[1], f), x0, bounds=bounds, x_scale=[a0_scale, b0_scale], verbose = 2)
    #print(ans.x)

    ########################
    #### my implementation
    ########################
    # bounds for own implementation
    bounds = [a0_bounds, b0_bounds]

    n = 0   # initialize iteration
    N = 100 # max iterations

    # initial error array and weights array
    errors = myMinimizingFunc(x0[0], x0[1], f)
    weights = x0.copy()
    prev_mse = 0

    while (mse(errors) > 0.01
            and n < N
            and not np.round(mse(errors), decimals=3) == np.round(prev_mse, decimals=3)):

        # adjust independent variables (weights)
        for i, w in enumerate(weights):
            weights[i] =  w + 1/a0_scale*x0[i]*sum(np.gradient(errors))/len(errors) # compute new weight

            # check if bounds are violated:
            if weights[i] > bounds[i][1]:
                weights[i] = bounds[i][1]
            if weights[i] < bounds[i][0]:
                weights[i] = bounds[i][0]
        # measure system
        prev_mse = mse(errors)
        errors = myMinimizingFunc(weights[0], weights[1], f)
        print(f'{n} MSE: {mse(errors):.2f}\t(Sum of err)/N: {sum(errors)/len(errors):.2f}\tind. variables: [{weights[0]:.2f},{weights[1]:.2f}]')
        #input('Press Enter to continue...')
        n = n+1
```

#### Output:

```
python3 least-squares-implementation.py
0 MSE: 2079.02  (Sum of err)/N: -0.06   ind. variables: [1.50,4.49]
1 MSE: 13.87    (Sum of err)/N: 0.29    ind. variables: [1.38,4.14]
2 MSE: 0.16     (Sum of err)/N: 0.26    ind. variables: [1.39,4.17]
3 MSE: 0.07     (Sum of err)/N: 0.26    ind. variables: [1.39,4.17]
4 MSE: 0.07     (Sum of err)/N: 0.26    ind. variables: [1.39,4.17]
```